# 403 Forbidden on Safari and Chrome, opens in Firefox

Tags: firefox, webkit, http-status-code-500

I am trying to open a web site http://www.fk-austria.at/. It worked fine a week ago, but now I can't seem to open it with neither Safari or Chrome, but it loads if I use Firefox. I tried clearing the cache and deleting the cookies. Is the problem in the server, or in the client?

Comment: I would say server problem (could reproduce from my side). It says *"You don't have permission to access / on this server."* Maybe there is no correct index page defined in the .htaccess? It also loads with IE.

Comment: FYI, it does not load in either Chrome or Firefox... The problem should be @ server side.

Comment: I also reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1):

Works for me with Opera and Chromium.  If you can browse to any website but that one, it may be blocked.

*Follow up*
It did not work for me with Chrome on a Windows machine.  They may be blocking certain browsers for some reason.  Nothing you can do about it.